# Takes to many RAM when start Android Studio and only one emulator

Tags: android-studio-2.3

Windows 7 (64 bit), RAM = 8 GB, Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM), 3.10 GHz.
Android Studio 2.3.

My machine before start Android Studio:
[image]

My machine after start Android Studio AND only one emulator(RAM 512 MB):

[image]

It's take 7 GB. As result work very difficult.

Any advice, how fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you're not working with Xamarin.

However, I would like to share the following:

I Recommend at least 16 gigs of RAM when doing mobile development with Xamarin.
I had the same issue with my previous machine that was 12 gigs of RAM.

In my case I was doing Xamarin development which consumes a huge amount of resources. In addition, I also upgraded to SSD.

Comment: I'm not use Xamarin and can't use it. Use only Android Studio 2.3

Comment: I'm suggesting that mobile development requires a beefy machine to do it on.